# Can race conditions occur in TestNG @Test?

Tags: scala, testng, race-condition

I have written a couple of tests, very identical but different in only one way. One test has an international address and the other has domestic address: `DomesticAddress`.scala & `InternationalAddress`.scala

`DomesticAddress`.scala extends another class `ShipMethods`.scala that has a `@Test` method. Here I am validating that `DomesticAddress`.scala has valid ship methods present. `InternationalAddress`.scala does *not* extend `ShipMethods`.scala.

Both test classes (`DomesticAddress`.scala and `InternationalAddress`.scala) have different users; the only similarity is that the address is stored in a val named 'address'.

When I run these two tests some times (and only some times) the test fails for `DomesticAddress`.scala because I see an international address in there.

**Is it possible that there is a race condition happening in this scenario?** My testng xml is preserving the order of tests, so this is more confusing that a race condition could occur especially since I am not sharing any resources among the tests.

Comment: Let's start with the obvious question: are you running your tests in parallel? (print the thread id in each if you're not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Why does your ShipMethods have a @Test annotation on it? Is it a test class? If it's not a test class (as opposed to a class which you want to test), then it shouldn't have a @Test annotation on it.

Your classes under test shouldn't have test methods inside them.